# Change the opacity of all elements except the one selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, opacity

I have three images on a single page and I would like to fade out the elements that aren't clicked on.  The script works in the first instance so if you click on one picture, the other two fade.  If you think click on an already faded picture, all that happens is that last non-faded picture also fades, instead of it being 100% opacity and the other two faded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.opac {
        filter:alpha(opacity=50);
        -moz-opacity:0.5;
        -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
        opacity: 0.5;
        border:thick;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.images').click(function()
    {
        $(this).siblings().stop().animate({opacity: 0.4}, 300);
        $('a.images').click(function()
        {
            $not('this').stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, 300);
    });
});
});
</script>






</head>


html

    <body>
        <div id="images">
        <a class="images" href="#"><img class="click" src="../appalachia.jpg" height="133" /><br/><br/></a>
        <a class="images" href="#"><img class="click" src="../appalachia.jpg" height="133" /><br/><br/></a>
        <a class="images" href="#"><img class="click" src="../appalachia.jpg" height="133" /><br/><br/></a>
        </div>

        </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: You don't need `-khtml-*` rules anymore, they've become obsolete. Moreover, don't forget to set `zoom: 1` to trigger `hasLayout` in IE <= 7, otherwise the `filter` will not be applied.

Comment: @Marcel: Do you need `-webkit-*` rules?

Comment: @Rocket: according to [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/opacity#Browser_compatibility), plain `opacity` is supported by all current WebKit-based browsers, so: no, you also don't need those. BTW, the same is true for `-moz-opacity`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this code:

```
$('a.images').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().stop().animate({opacity: 0.4}, 300);
    $('a.images').click(function() {
        $not('this').stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, 300);
    });
});
```

you're registering a click handler over and over, for each click.  Just try this instead:

```
$('a.images').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().stop().animate({opacity: 0.4}, 300);
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, 300);
});
```

Comment: why did you use `siblings()` ?

Answer (score 5):

You are attaching a `click` handler inside a `click` handler.  Every time you click, a new click handler will be added and called on each subsequent click.

Click handlers are called with the newest added called first, which means that last, all the images are set to transparent.

If you want the picture you clicked on to be opaque, and the others transparent, try this:

```
$('a.images').click(function(){
    // Make all images (except this) transparent
    $('a.images').not(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0.4}, 300);
    // Make this opaque
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, 300);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gCsRL/1/

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't quite clear :). I did have code that worked like that but what I was looking for was for only one element to be faded at a time.  So if you clicked on picture 1, then 2 and 3 fade.  If you click on 3, 3 will be at full opacity and 1 and 2 will be faded.  sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: @dzilla: The question was clear; this comment isn't clear.  You say "only one element to be faded at a time", but then you say "2 and 3 fade".  What exactly do you want?  I've added a link to a demo to my answer, click on that and try it out.

Comment: You know what? I had a complete brain fart.  You were right! :)